# Setting content view hierarchy

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm developing an app that implements a simple compass.

I'm creating and manipulating the compass itself in a class (Rose.java) that extends ImageView.

On my main activity I want to add the rose object to the layout and I have this code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
  sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

  rose = new Rose (this);


  setContentView(rose);
  }
```

The thing is, as you know, by using the setContentView the "rose" is going to be full screen and the rest of the elements of the layout won't show.

I'm asking specifically for an alternate method that adds the rose object to the layout without neglecting the rest of its elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could allocate width and height of say LinearLayout in xml.

Define a LinearLayout in your xml file and define the width and height of your choice. Place the layout where you like. Add the content of the custom view to LinearLayout

```
   setContentView(R.id.activity_main);
   LinearLayout ll =  (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
   rose = new Rose(this);
   ll.addView(rose);
```

Example:

actiivty_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
   // Other views like textview's and button above linear layout

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="40dp" // mention the width of you choice
       android:layout_height="40dp"  // // mention the height of you choice
       android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
       >
   </LinearLayout>
        // other views below linear layout
</RelativeLayout>
```